# Telethon выбрасывает со всех авторизированных аккаунтов

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync


api_id = 1234567
api_hash = ""


client = TelegramClient('tg_session', api_id, api_hash,)
client.start()

print(client.get_me())
```

При входе в свой аккаунт через телетон выбрасывает со всех авторизированных устройств, а также выбрасывает из сессии телетона, т.е я запускаю код, ввожу номер, ввожу код, который пришел мне в тг, после все авторизированные аккаунты слетают, а так же при повторном запуске кода, телетон опять просит ввести номер телефона

Comment: Вам удалось решить эту проблему? У меня такая же ситуация!

Comment: Вы решили эту проблему? У меня такая-же

Comment: У меня такая же проблема решить не получилось, если есть кто может помочь готов заплатить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло добавление параметра `system_version` в конструктор класса `TelegramClient`:

```
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash,
                        system_version='4.16.30-vxCUSTOM')
```

Затем в самом клиенте Телеграма ответить на вопрос об авторизации "Да, это я"

И проблем больше не возникало.

P.S. Некоторые люди пишут, что им пришлось еще указывать параметры `device_model` и `app_version`